# Updating httpd.conf not working for permalinks

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, httpd.conf, permalinks

I am unable to set permalinks to end with post names. I receive a 404 error. The closest I got is to set custom permalink to:

```
/index.php/%postname%
```

But this causes 'index.php' to show up in the URL. I also updated my httpd.conf to set the root dir to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

But it still does not work. My wordpress is hosted on AWS EC2 linux AMI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activate the mod_rewrite module with

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and restart the apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

To use mod_rewrite from within .htaccess files (which is a very common use case), edit the default VirtualHost with

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Below “DocumentRoot /var/www/html” add the following lines:

```
<Directory “/var/www/html”>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Restart the server again:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

EDIT:

Found my htaccess file was missing. So followed the steps listed here :

https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/#wheres-my-htaccess-file

- Created htaccess in wp root which, on my server, was /var/www/html.
- Added the required rewrite rules provided in the link above.
- Set chmod on htaccess to 775
- Set chown on htaccess to apache:apache
- Restarted httpd service

Postname permalink now works!

Comment: The AMI I am using has httpd service not apache2.  So, these steps dont apply.

Comment: Have you tried below steps :  https://devops.ionos.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-centos-7/

Comment: Thank you!!! Your link didn't have the exact solution, but it showed me I was missing the .thaccess file. mod_rewrite was already enabled. I just needed to create htaccess. I will update your answer with the additional steps and accept it.